# Jenkins build tar error

Tags: linux, jenkins

I'm having a build problem with jenkins, it has been working several months without any
problems, but now it says:

**tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Checking console output
Finished: FAILURE**

I tried to put more verbose to this build, but still the same error occurs.
I have looked from the shell logs and found that same error in there,
also I matched old build logs to this one and I cannot find any
several errors that would do this.

There's plenty of disk space left, also i raised open files, but the problem stays the same.

Could newly added class files do this kind of problem?

--bp

Comment: Are you following symbolic links or trying to read files you (Jenkins, group, or other) don't have read permission? For debugging problems, I usually go to ~jenkins/jobs/_project_name_/workspace and manually execute the same command from the commandline.

Comment: I runned the script from shell and did output > to_a_file, so i could see the error. Error was that 1 directory which script includes was deleted and no one bothered to mention to me about it. --bp